# Set placeholder views count in Android Listview

Tags: android, listview

I'm trying to build a smooth-scrolling ListView in Android using Universal Image Loader. The only problem remaining is resetting ImageView when in hides and shown again. E. g., Android recycles child view when it is not shown, but I want to keep in memory for some time (e. g. 3 view are shown, and 2 view before and 2 views after are still not recycled).

Is it possible to set children count for the ListView to store in memory?

Comment: What is the reason you want to do that? Isn't your ListView performant enough? If so what is the bottle neck? Is it assigning the image?

Comment: The problem is following - my imageview is reset on every render, so my listview looks not so smooth when I scroll a little forward and backward